# Background reason for the terms ‘Isotropic’ and ‘Anisotropic’ in the context of GNN Message Passing

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, aggregation, symmetry, graph-neural-network

I’m reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.00982) on Graph Neural Networks (GNNs) that uses the terms ‘isotropic’ and ‘anisotropic’ in the context of message passing. I understand that [these terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropy) originate from physics, chemistry, and mathematics, but I’m struggling to find an analogy or reason for their use in this paper. Could anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 1):

It is also used in Geometry, as seen below:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropy

Isotropic indicates that a given property does not change given the direction
Anisotropic means a given property does change given the direction.

In GNNs it is used to differentiate between Networks in which the receiving node is influencing the message passed or not:

[image]
https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.01481

So in this example, the message sent on the right remains independent of x, while in the left case, a change in x will change the message sent.
So which x the message being sent to can be understood as the direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand your explanation and I guess it's most likely true, but in my opinion, the analogy is somehow poor. Since we can't observe this analogy in a large macroscopic scale.

Comment: I think if you are bothered by people using wrong terminology, then you will have to suffer a lot when doing AI research :D They misappropriate like they are 18th century britain.